# RPG Maker (Issue) RGSS_RTP STANDARD

Tags: rpg-maker-xp

the issue i am having is rpg maker is installed onto my computer as well a rgss-rtp standard and when i go to run RPG maker it says RGSS-RTP STANDARD not installed?
how can i get it to run?

Comment: Make sure you installed rgss-rtp into the right directory. The easiest solution would be uninstalling both and installing them in the default directories.

Comment: yeah opk i did that but the same error came up again

Answer (score 1):

If you have the complete installer for RPG Maker XP (of course, with RTP for RGSS1), you can install it there directly. Open your rpg maker xp installer and you can see the 'Install RTP' button. Click that and you are ready to go.